# filter regex to percentage

Tags: regex, percentage

I would like two examples of regular expression to filter percentage:

I have the following cases:

Case 1:

```
Increased % 3.05
Increased % 8.05
Increased % 12.05
```

Case 2:

```
Increased % 3.05
Increased % 8.05
Increased % 12.05
```

In case 1, I would like a regular expression to filter any percentage above `8%`, example: `Increased % 8.05`
In case 2, I would like a regular expression to filter any percentage above `10%`, example: `Increased % 12.05`

Any idea how to assemble a regex string for case 1 and case 2?

I don't have much knowledge in regex and all the alternatives I tested didn't come close to the expected result.

Comment: Something along these lines maybe? `([8-9]|\d{2,})\.\d+%` https://regex101.com/r/usAHL4/1

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't do that with pure regex alone, except maybe for a run-once-and-throw-away script. It can be done, but it will be next to impossible to decipher later. Regex is meant for matching text patterns, not things like arithmetic comparison. You could use regex just to extract the percentage value strings, than programmatically parse them to a float and filter by numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter above 10%:

```
^.*%\s*[1-9]\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/FPm59p/1)

`[1-9]\d+(?:\.\d+)?` -> matches `1` to `9` and one or more digits + optional decimal part

---

To filter above 8%:

```
^.*%\s*(?:8|\d\d+)(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/rrLfeq/1)

`(?:8|\d\d+)(?:\.\d+)?` -> matches `8` or two or more digits + optional decimal part

Comment: For above 10%, your case doesnt match 2x, 3x% etc... I think [1-9] instead of 1 would fix

Comment: Hello, thanks everyone, these two strings helped to work around my problem